# Is there a repository of free to use, modular, css styles?

Tags: css, stylesheet

I'm putting together a small website, and as a programmer (not designer) I think in terms of small, modular, reusable units. So instead of writing all my css from scratch I wish there were something like a repository of CSS styles that had various CSS elements (formfields, typography, buttons, layouts) with screenshots, so I can windowshop and mix and match the things I want, get the code and assemble everything together on my site.

I know there are CSS theme sites, but with those you get the whole site, and if out of an entire theme you just want to borrow a button then you have to dig deep into the theme's css and extract all the relevant css attributes yourself (I guess firebug etc would help here, but still).

There's also snippet sites, but those host CSS incidentally, and aren't meant to be used as I described (there's no screenshots to see what the styles look like).

Also scattered around the web there are small libraries for a particular element (like navigation menus, or forms). These are closer to what I want, but there seems to be no single repository to host them all (no github of css, so to speak). The best you get is one of those "40 awesome css navigation menus"-type articles.

There *has* to be something like this. If not, can someone please build it (or tell me why it can't be built).

Comment: You just gave me the perfect idea to set this up. there are some difficulties with tgis though with css inherentance when opeople use sloppy css coding like body span { all my stuff here}

Comment: Can you please set this up by tonight and populate with thousands of styles? :)

Comment: You'd hardly need screenshots though since the styles can just be previewed in the browser

Comment: Hehe, that would be a bit much, but its a nice business model for a site. I will see if I can set it up coming week. I really like the concept.

Comment: @whitman [Google "free css snippets"](http://www.google.com/search?q=free+css+snippets) -> http://css-tricks.com/snippets/. Whenever you need a specific style, a quick search on Google usually yields the desired solution (provided that you specify the right keywords).

Comment: I thought that's what OOCSS was going to be, but it never seemed to go anywhere. I actually think of Twitter Bootstrap as being a good repository of CSS design patterns, though its probably fiddly to separate individual components from the entire framework.